# Ubuntu OS update from 18.04 to 22.04 issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kwLL.png) I am getting above attached error after doing do-release-update please help me on this.

we have try to add the api.snapcraft.io in firewall but still getting error.
After add the api.snapcaft.io in firewall we are able to telenet.